# Change Xdebug Mode PHP Docker on Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, phpunit, xdebug

I want run PHPUnit code coverage using GitLab CI but when i run the command `vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never` is only show code test result and not generating code coverage.

When I test it on local using XAMPP with Xdebug enable the code coverage generated with using `xdebug.mode=coverage`. How to change the `xdebug.mode` on php.ini on docker setup script ?

I also override it via PHPUnit XML configuration like this also not work.

`<ini name="xdebug.mode" value="coverage" />`

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: php:7.4.14

cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    - vendor

before_script:
  # Install git
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install git -yqq

  # Install packages
  - apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

  # Install required php extension
  - docker-php-ext-install curl

  # Install Xdebug
  - pecl install xdebug
  - docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

  # Install composer
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

  # Install dependencies
  - php composer.phar update --prefer-stable --prefer-dist --no-interaction --no-progress

run-test:
  script:
    - vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching some article finally i can do it like this.
Here my example `.gitlab-ci.yml`

image: php:7.4.14

```
cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    - vendor

before_script:
  # Install git
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install git -yqq

  # Install packages
  - apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

  # Install required php extension
  - docker-php-ext-install curl

  # Install Xdebug
  - pecl install xdebug
  - docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

  # Install composer
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

  # Install dependencies
  - php composer.phar update --prefer-stable --prefer-dist --no-interaction --no-progress

  # Here to change xdebug mode
  - echo xdebug.mode=coverage > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini 

run-test:
  script:
    - vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
```

Comment: Quick question, make sense... But only to be sure. The correct approach is override `>` the entire `xdebug.ini` file instead of append a new line `>>` correct?

Answer (score 2):

In my dockerfile I added this lines :

```
RUN pecl install xdebug \
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
&& echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.mode=coverage" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```